# How can I use input/search between multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a site where you can search up any country and it'll show you detailed information on it using REST Countries API. I want to have a first HTML page with just a search box in the middle where you type your country. You then press search and it'll redirect you to another HTML page where I've set up a template for the countries flag, capital, population, currency, region, and subregion.

I have no clue how to connect them and I've tried messing with the input box id value, looking at search bar & REST Countries API tutorials, but I've figured out nothing. I added a search box to the page where I want ONLY the information to be displayed for testing and it works if I type in the exact country name and it is case sensitive.

How could I even connect these pages & search bar? And if it is possible, how could I make it suggest me countries after I type in one letter?

Main HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ae3cf15842.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>CountryProjectA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <div class="search-box" >
                <input class= "search-txt" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for a country" />
                <a class="search-btn" href="">
                    <i class="fas fa-search-location fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Country info display HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/info-style.css">
    <title>Info</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Countries</h1>
    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="flag-container">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="info-container">
            <input name="" id="countries"></select>
            <p>Capital: <span id="capital"></span></p>
            <p>Population: <span id="population"></span></p>
            <p>Currencies: <span id="currencies"></span></p>
            <p>Region: <span id="region"></span></p>
            <p>Subregion: <span id="subregion"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main JS

```
const countriesList = document.getElementById("countries");
let countries;

countriesList.addEventListener("change", newCountrySelection);

function newCountrySelection(event) {
  displayCountryInfo(event.target.value);
}

fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => initialize(data))
.catch(err => console.log("Error:", err));

function initialize(countriesData) {
  countries = countriesData;
  let options = "";

  countries.forEach(country => options+=`<option value="${country.alpha3Code}">${country.name}</option>`);
  countriesList.innerHTML = options;
  countriesList.selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*countriesList.length);
  displayCountryInfo(countriesList[countriesList.selectedIndex].value);
}

function displayCountryInfo(countryByName) {
  const countryData = countries.find(country => country.name === countryByName);
  document.querySelector("#flag-container img").src = countryData.flag;
  document.querySelector("#flag-container img").alt = `Flag of ${countryData.name}`;  
  document.getElementById("capital").innerHTML = countryData.capital;
  document.getElementById("population").innerHTML = countryData.population.toLocaleString("en-US");
  document.getElementById("currencies").innerHTML = countryData.currencies.filter(c => c.name).map(c => `${c.name} (${c.code})`).join(", ");
  document.getElementById("region").innerHTML = countryData.region;
  document.getElementById("subregion").innerHTML = countryData.subregion;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: In search box, you can return link with country info, for example, mysite.com?country=USA and then in another page read the link and get county info and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to get the input value in your Javascript code when someone clicks the search button.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search-btn")[0].onclick = function() {
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("search").value;
  // call the search function here and redirect to the other page where you display results.
}
```

As for suggesting names, you can use the Google Places Autocomplete API for that: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete. Just call the API in the `oninput` event handler for `#search`.

Hope this helps!